# Android, Realm: After add annotation @PrimaryKey get error: Following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:

Tags: android, realm

Realm 3.5.0. 
I get json from external system. And I need to save this json to Realm.

Here json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "address": "Address 1",
    "contactsIds": [10, 20, 30, 40],
    "name": "Person 1"
}
```

In my Android application:

So I create POJO for Person:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private RealmList<RealmInt> contactsIds = new RealmList<>();
}
```

My POJO for RealmInt:

```
public class RealmInt extends RealmObject {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

My custom json deserializer for **RealmInt** (by GSON):

```
public class RealmIntAdapterJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RealmInt> {

    @Override
    public RealmInt deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        RealmInt realmInt = new RealmInt();
        realmInt.setValue(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt());
        return realmInt;
    }
}
```

Snippet that save json to Realm:

```
    public void fromJsonToRealm(final String someJson) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
               Person person = JsonUtil.gson.fromJson(someJson, Person.class);
               realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(person);

            }
        });
}
```

Result of call method "fromJsonToRealm" is:

- In table "**Person**" was create one record
- In table "**RealmInt**" was create 4 records (10, 20, 30, 40)

OK.

Table "**Person**" and "**RealmInt**" must be share with many Android devices. So I use **SyncConfiguration** for this.
Here snippet:

```
    private void setRealmDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser) { 
         SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, REALM_URL).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config); 
    }
```

So now I want to update this person.
I get the new json (for same **Person**) with updated data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "address": "Address new",
    "contactsIds": [10, 20],
    "name": "Person new"
}
```

I again start method "**fromJsonToRealm**" and as result it success update ONE record in table "**Person**", *BUT add* new 2 records in table "**RealmInt**".
As result in table "**RealmInt**" I has 6 records.

But I want to update(not insert) records in table "**RealmInt**" when I update same object "**Person**".

So then I add annotation **@PrimaryKey** to field "value" in object "**RealmInt**".

But when I start again method "**fromJsonToRealm**" I get error:

```
E/REALM_JNI( 9018): jni: ThrowingException 8, The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:
E/REALM_JNI( 9018): - Primary Key for class 'RealmInt' has been added., .
E/REALM_JNI( 9018): Exception has been thrown: The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:
E/REALM_JNI( 9018): - Primary Key for class 'RealmInt' has been added.
```

So the question is: How I can update exist record in table "**Person**" when get updated json for SAME object **Person**?

Comment: `Additive-only schema mode` you're using SyncConfiguration, right?

Comment: Yes. Here code:     `private void setRealmDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser) {
        SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, REALM_URL).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }`  . Table "Person" and "RealmInt" must be share with many other android  devices.

Answer (score 1):

Adding/removing `@PrimaryKey` is considered a "destructive" schema operation, so it is not allowed in sync mode.

With your current schema setup, you ought to delete the existing `RealmInt`s from the Realm before you copy the new Person in.

```
public void fromJsonToRealm(final String someJson) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
               Person person = JsonUtil.gson.fromJson(someJson, Person.class);
               long personId = person.getId();
               Person managedPerson = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", personId).findFirst();
               if(managedPerson != null) {
                   managedPerson.getContactIds().deleteAllFromRealm();
               }
               realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(person);
            }
        });
    }
```

Another option would be to implement some smarter merge logic

```
public void fromJsonToRealm(final String someJson) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
               Person person = JsonUtil.gson.fromJson(someJson, Person.class);
               long personId = person.getId();
               Person managedPerson = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", personId).findFirst();
               if(managedPerson != null) {
                   boolean wasFound = false;
                   for(RealmInt existingInt : managedPerson.getContactIds()) {
                       for(RealmInt newInt : person.getContactIds()) {
                           if(existingInt.getValue() == newInt.getValue()) {
                               wasFound = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       if(!wasFound) {
                           existingInt.deleteFromRealm();
                       }
                   }
                   Iterator<RealmInt> newIntIterator = person.getContactIds().iterator();
                   while(newIntIterator.hasNext()) {
                       RealmInt newInt = newIntIterator.next();
                       boolean wasFound = false;
                       for(RealmInt existingInt : managedPerson.getContactIds()) {
                           if(existingInt.getValue() == newInt.getValue()) {
                               wasFound = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                       if(!wasFound) {
                           newIntIterator.remove();
                       }
                   }
               }
               realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(person);
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S. I don't use `RealmList<RealmInt>`s, I prefer to just save them as a comma separated string. Realm Core 3.0.0 will make this use-case much easier though.

Comment: So you think that use filed _personsIds_ as **String** is the better approach?
Smt like this: `public class Person extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    private String address;

    // comma separated string, e.g. "[10, 20, 30]"
    private String contactsIds; 
}`   ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Depends on how you're querying them later, because if you need to query for `contains`, and your IDs can have both `10` and `100`, then something like `,10,100,` is better - as that way you can query against `"," + number + ","` in a reliable manner. This is what I tend to think about a lot, considering `RealmList<Integer>` isn't supported yet (although the next major release will have core support, so it's gonna happen in a few months).